# How can I customize the positions of legend elements?

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I have a figure with several plots and a legend. Is it possible to change the arrangement of the elements in the legend manually? For example, how could you make a two-column legend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course this is possible. See an explanation here: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/multi-column-grid-legend/

Answer (score 6):

To make a two-column legend, the general consensus seems to be that you need to create two separate legends and manually place them side by side.  Solution simplified from [discussion here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/157048).

```
x = 1:10;
y1 = rand(1, 10);
y2 = rand(1, 10);

h1 = plot(x, y1, '-');
hold on
h2 = plot(x, y2, '-.r');

ah1 = gca;
ah2 = axes('position',get(gca,'position'), 'visible','off');

legend(ah1, h1, 'Location', [0.5 0.85 0.15 0.05], 'y1')
legend(ah2, h2, 'Location', [0.7 0.85 0.15 0.05], 'y2')
```

Comment: This works! The most important trick in this answer is `'Location', [0.5 0.85 0.15 0.05]` where the latter vector has a following interpretation: `[Position_Right_in_pct,  Position_Top_in_pct,   Horizontal_Stretch  Vertical_Stretch]`

Answer (score 1):

There are two submissions on the [MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) which create multi-column legends for you:

- [columnlegend](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27389-columnlegend) by [Simon Henin](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/83564) (which was a MATLAB Central [Pick of the Week](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2011/02/11/create-multi-column-plot-legends/))
- [gridLegend - a multi column format for legends](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29248) by [Adrian Cherry](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/40041)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the submissions mentioned by @gnovice, there is another one on the MathWorks File Exchange which also create multi-column legends

- [legendflex: a more flexible legend](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31092-legendflex-a-more-flexible-legend) by [Kelly Kearney](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/17594)

Answer (score 0):

In 2018a, legend has a NumColumns parameter; e.g., if h is an array of handles to lines plotted, and leg_names is a cell array of names for each line:

```
hleg = legend(h, leg_names, 'FontSize', fontsize);
set(hleg, 'NumColumns', 2);
set(hleg, 'Location', 'south');
```